# Pull NULL if column not present in table while UNION SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, union, sql-server-2014-express

I am currently building a dynamic SQL query. The tables and columns are sent as parameters. So the columns may not be present in the table. Is there a way to pull `NULL` data in the result set when the column is not present in the table?

ex:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
created date | Name  | Salary | Married
-------------+-------+--------+----------
25-Jan-2016  | Chris |  2500  | Y
27-Jan-2016  | John  |  4576  | N
30-Jan-2016  | June  |  3401  | N
```

So when I run the query below

```
SELECT Created_date, Name, Age, Married 
FROM Table1
```

I need to get

```
created date | Name  |  AGE   | Married
-------------+-------+--------+----------
25-Jan-2016  | Chris |  NULL  | Y
27-Jan-2016  | John  |  NULL  | N
30-Jan-2016  | June  |  NULL  | N
```

Does anything like `IF NOT EXISTS` or `ISNULL` work in this?

I can't use extensive T-SQL in this segment and need to be simple since I am creating a UNION query to more than 50 tables (requirement :| ) . Any advice would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of an easy solution. Since you're using dynamic sql, instead of

```
(previous dynamic string part)+' fieldname '+(next dynamic string part)
```

you could use

```
(previous dynamic string part)
+ case when exists (
select 1 
from sys.tables t 
inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id
where c.name=your_field_name and t.name=your_table_name)
) then ' fieldname ' else ' NULL ' end
+(next dynamic string part)
```

Comment: I can not do this for all the columns for all the tables :| .. On an average there are 10 columns sent as params..

Comment: All I can say is...I'm sorry! I don't know any other way. If there is, it'll probably pop up as another answer here shortly.

Comment: You only need to do this once - inside a loop.  Assume you are building your select statement in a string var where you loop over tables and then inner loop over fields.  If the field exists append it to select clause.  If not append `NULL AS FieldName`.

Comment: nice idea destination-data!

Comment: @destination-data that is what I am currently planning to do but would be nice if there is a better way to do it rather than joining with sys tables. MS should really think of little issues like this. IF ERROR( SELECT AGE FROM Table1, NULL) would be great.

Comment: you *could* use try-catch logic to do what you are saying, but it seems even more of a headache. To be honest, I wouldn't blame MS for not having something like this - it is an exotic, in my opinion.